# How do I purchase limpets at a station?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm relatively new to Elite: Dangerous, and can't figure out how to purchase limpets at a station. I've already outfitted my ship with a limpet controller, but don't have any limpets (ammunition) for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purchasing limpets has moved around a couple of times. In the current version of Elite: Dangerous (2.2), follow these steps:

1. Dock at a station
2. Choose **Starport Services**
3. Click on **Advanced Maintenance**
4. Click on **Restock**

You'll be able to purchase limpets from this screen.

Comment: Note that you must also be at a station with restock services available. For example, Li Qing Jao Starport in Sol has no restock services. Damaged stations will likely also not have restock services.